# Why does my picture not come in my website?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make an animated footer. I have tried to put a picture in my code, but it is not showing.

**EDIT**
i tried editing the code as told, but the picture still won't show. My css file is in the same folder as my wave.png, but the wave.png is inside another folder in the same folder. I'm not sure if this is the issue or not. I can also show my whole code if that is necessary

```css
footer .wave {
  position: absolute;
  top: -100px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: #f00 url(wave.png);
  background-size: 1000px 100px;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div class="waves">
    <div class="wave" id="wave1"></div>
    <div class="wave" id="wave2"></div>
    <div class="wave" id="wave3"></div>
    <div class="wave" id="wave4"></div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Without more information is difficult to help you, but i can imagine that the path to your `wave.png` file isn't correct. If you go to your inspector's network tab do you see the file being loaded there?

Comment: I edited your question to include `</footer>` at the end; I'm assuming you have that in your original code?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score -2):

edit

```
footer .wave
```

to

```
.waves .wave
```

remove

```
background: #f00 url(wave.png);
```

add

```
background-color: #f00;
background-image: url(wave.png);
```

Be sure that you have wave.png in the same directory/folder as the css file, if your css file is in a (for example) css/ folder and the image is in /images folder you will have to change url to

```
background-image: url(../images/wave.png);
```

Comment: How does separating out for example background-color and background-image make it different from using the combined form of background?

Comment: i did as told. But the picture is still not showing. Should i show you my full code?

Comment: Please do show the full code

Comment: if the wave.png is in a folder that its in the same css folder then update 
background-image: url(../images/wave.png);
to
background-image: url(yourfolder/wave.png);

Comment: for some reason i can't putt my full code here. But i did change background-image(url) to to background-image: url(yourfolder/wave.png);